# Vim: Why is ^[[I showing up?

Tags: vim

After exiting Vim sometimes I notice one or more `^[[I` sequences appearing by my command line prompt, e.g. `^[[I^[[I^[[I$`.  Why might this be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I tracked down the issue to a few lines of the following form in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
silent !mkdir -p ~/.vim/.undo >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Replacing them with the following longer form resolved the issue:

```
if !isdirectory($HOME."/.vim/.undo")
  call mkdir($HOME."/.vim/.undo", "p")
endif
```